# Get Active Users vs Total Users till Google Analytics is set up

Tags: google-analytics

I need to get the total number of users that've visited my website vs users visited only last week.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've worded the question sounds like you need to know it before Google Analytics is set up? If it is already set up, there's an easy way to compare in Analytics if you go Audience > Overview and change the date in the right corner.

[image showing the date range tool in Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmRgq.png)

If it's before you're setting up Google Analytics, unless your website's CMS has a reporting section there's no way to check.